# how to publish in Hedis haskell pubSub

Tags: haskell, redis

I'm currently learning Haskell. Now I'm currently not that good in functional programming.
I want to make a piece of code, that get's data from subscribing on a topic in Redis, do some calculation on it and publishing it on a other topic. I'm having trouble with I guess some language specific features.

My current code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Database.Redis
import System.IO

main = do 
    conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
    runRedis conn $ do
        pubSub (subscribe ["commands"]) $ \msg -> do
            putStrLn $ "Message from " ++ show (msgChannel msg)
            publish "results" "Result of a very interesting calculation"
            return mempty
```

Now I receive the error:  `• No instance for (RedisCtx IO f0) arising from a use of ‘publish’`

Putting the publish outside the pubsub will make it work. But I want to publish a result! I can't get any wiser from the documentation. What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `putStrLn` is making the typechecker (correctly!) infer that your `do` block is intended to be in an `IO` context, then the call to `publish` requires the context to be an instance of `RedisCtx`, which `IO` is not.

Normally in a `Redis` context, the solution would be to lift the `IO` action into the `Redis` context using `liftIO :: IO a -> m a` from the [`MonadIO`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html) class, as in the example in the documentation:

```
runRedis conn $ do
    set "hello" "hello"
    set "world" "world"
    helloworld <- multiExec $ do
        hello <- get "hello"
        world <- get "world"
        return $ (,) <$> hello <*> world
    liftIO (print helloworld)
```

`MonadIO` is the set of types in whose context you can execute `IO` actions.

However, in this case, it’s the other way around: the functional parameter to `pubSub` returns an `IO` action, but `publish` expects a `RedisCtx` monad.

It’s not clear to me whether `pubSub` allows you to make a `runRedis` call inside the callback, like this, although I think it should typecheck:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

import Database.Redis
import System.IO

main = do 
    conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo
    runRedis conn $ do
        pubSub (subscribe ["commands"]) $ \msg -> do
            putStrLn $ "Message from " ++ show (msgChannel msg)
            runRedis conn $ publish "results" "Result of a very interesting calculation"
            return mempty
```

Based on skimming the docs, each `runRedis` call takes a connection from the connection pool, whose default size is 50; however, if there is no available connection, it blocks, so my concern is that because the docs for `pubSub` say it’s “single-threaded”, this could deadlock waiting for a connection that won’t be released since you’re in a “nested” `runRedis` call.

I think the thing I would try next is to use the more flexible `pubSubForever` API; in the [`hedis` test suite](https://github.com/informatikr/hedis/blob/master/test/ManualPubSub.hs) there’s an example of using `pubSubForever` with separate threads for publishing and handling subscription events.

```
main = do
  ctrl <- newPubSubController [("foo", msgHandler)] []
  conn <- connect defaultConnectInfo

  withAsync (publishThread conn) $ \_pubT -> do
    withAsync (handlerThread conn ctrl) $ \_handlerT -> do

      void $ hPutStrLn stderr "Press enter to subscribe to bar" >> getLine
      void $ addChannels ctrl [("bar", msgHandler)] []
      -- …
      -- (Add/remove various subscriptions.)
      -- …
```

`publishThread` uses `runRedis` and calls `publish`:

```
publishThread :: Connection -> IO ()
publishThread c = runRedis c $ loop (0 :: Int)
  where
    loop i = do
      let msg = encodeUtf8 $ pack $ "Publish iteration " ++ show i
      void $ publish "foo" ("foo" <> msg)
      -- …
      liftIO $ threadDelay $ 2*1000*1000
      loop (i+1)
```

`handlerThread` uses `pubSubForever`:

```
handlerThread :: Connection -> PubSubController -> IO ()
handlerThread conn ctrl = forever $
       pubSubForever conn ctrl onInitialComplete
         `catch` (\(e :: SomeException) -> do
           hPutStrLn stderr $ "Got error: " ++ show e
           threadDelay $ 50*1000)
```

This is wrapped in a call to [`forever`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:forever) to resubscribe if the connection is lost, per the [docs for `pubSubForever`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedis-0.14.4/docs/Database-Redis.html#v:pubSubForever):

> […] if the network connection to Redis dies, `pubSubForever` will throw a `ConnectionLost`. When such an exception is thrown, you can recall `pubSubForever` with the same `PubSubController` which will open a new connection and resubscribe to all the channels which are tracked in the `PubSubController`.

This test uses `Control.Concurrent.Async` from the [`async`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async) package for managing tasks, which is a good idea imo. If you want to avoid that dependency, you could use `forkIO` instead (with e.g. a `Chan` or STM `TChan` to send events from the handler), the only issue is that this won’t automatically notify the other threads if the forked thread terminates due to an exception, whereas `Async` makes some nice exception safety guarantees.

Comment: You can avoid the extra dependency.  MonadIO is actually in base these days. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson: Thanks! Edited. Apparently I was confused by the link to `transformers` in the `hedis` docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help! However this still gives the same error.  also, if I remove the putStrLn it still won't work.

Comment: @Heiko: Ah, sorry, I was misreading the docs—updated. I’m guessing a bit tbh, but I compiled what info I could find and hope it puts you on the right track.